# Capturing the spec filename in a ruby DSL implementation?

Tags: ruby, dsl, objective-c++, vmat

I am writing a **ruby** DSL that will be used to code-generate a number of **Objective-C++** functions. I would like the name of each function to be derived from the name of its **ruby** DSL source file.

For example, given this source file `clusterOptions.rb`:

```
require './vMATCodeMonkey'

VMATCodeMonkey.new(:print).options_processor <<EOS
  -cutoff:    flag: set('useCutoff', true), arg: vector('double')
  -depth:     flag: set('useInconsistent', true), arg: scalar('double', default: 2.0)
  -maxclust:  flag: set('useCutoff', false), arg: vector('index')
EOS
```

When the `VMATCodeMonkey.new(:print)` expression is evaluated I would *ideally* somehow like the new object to capture the `clusterOptions.rb` source filename. Is that possible?

And if (as I suspect) it is not, is there a good idiom for accomplishing this functionality [e.g. making the source file name effectively part of the specification captured by a DSL] in **ruby**?

[While I *suspect* it's not possible to do exactly as I've described, I *ask anyway*, because I've been surprised by **ruby**'s obscure capabilities more than once.]

**EDIT:** I'm aware of `__FILE__`; what I'm looking for is some DSL-centric way of capturing the name of a DSL source file *without* explicitly mentioning `__FILE__` *in the DSL source*. Hmm, and now that I'm trying to explain it, maybe crawling up a stack trace from the class `initialize` method?

### Solution

With thanks to tadman, here is my `VMATCodeMonkey#initialize` method:

```
def initialize(out_opt = :print)
    @caller_file = caller(1)[0].split(':')[0]
    case out_opt
      when :pbcopy
        @out = IO.popen('pbcopy', 'w')
      when :print
        @out = $stdout
      else
        raise ArgumentError, "#{out_opt} is not an option!"
    end
    @out.puts "// vMATCodeMonkey's work; do not edit by hand!\n\n"
    initialize_options_processor
  end
```

And here's what it captures:

```
@caller_file = "/Users/Shared/Source/vMAT/ruby/clusterOptions.rb"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full path to the source file being evaluated is stored in `__FILE__`. If you want just the filename, you'd use:

```
File.basename(__FILE__)
```

The `__FILE__` constant is common to C, C++, Perl and Python, among others.

If you need to know what file made the call to the currently running routine, this could work:

```
caller(1)[0].split(':')[0]
```

This presumes your filenames do not have `:` in them, but in most cases that should be a fairly safe assumption. You'll also need to call this at the entry point into your library. If it's a method deeper in the stack, test `caller(2)` and so on.

Comment: I should have clarified that I've tried using `__FILE__`, but that it captures `vMATCodeMonkey.rb` and not `clusterOptions.rb`.